# populate SQL Lite with Huge data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, records

Hi

I need to insert thousands of records into Android - SQL LITE database, on first time of app installation. what is the optimize way to handle this situation. should i Hard code those records in LIST (code) or fetch from File System i.e, CSV or txt **or its any other way**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to keep your database file in the `assets folder` and the `copy` it into `databases` folder for the first time your application starts. Inserting thousands of record won't be a good idea if you are having static data in your tables.

Comment: THanks, i found this URL, http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/